# cp command used in script does not work properly

Tags: bash

i'm trying to write script asking about file and directory and then copying file. I wanted to do something looking that way:

```
#!/bin/bash
read FILE
read DIRECTORY
cp $FILE $DIRECOTRY
```

file and directory i choose do exist, but script does not work despite returning no error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix a typo: `cp "$FILE" "$DIRECTORY"` (`""` are to allow filenames with whitespaces), and then you can run your script, enter the two names on two lines and see the result. You can also add `-x` to see commands running. In full:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
read FILE
read DIRECTORY
cp "$FILE" "$DIRECTORY"
```

Comment: ok, thank You so much for response, especially for -x option, but "" didn't help. I was trying cp with "~" as my home directory. Now i'm writing full path (/home/ ... ) and it works! Now i'm wondering why  "~"  is not working.

Comment: Bash does not expand `~` within quotes. I suggest to replace `"~"` by `"$HOME"`.